# XSLT grouping siblings with conditions?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Could someone help me out with an unfinished idea?

Im not very used to xslt but im trying and thanks to a lot of internet help im getting along.

But:

following scenario i cannot solve:

Given an example XML with some geological layer data looking like that:

```
  <LAYERS> 
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="1.00" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_1" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="94.00" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_1" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="94.20" INTV="1" INDEX_ZONE="-1" EGART="Lost_Data"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="95.00" PETRO="Gravel" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_1" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="100.00" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_2" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="100.50" PETRO="Mud" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_2" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="101.50" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_2" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="101.80" PETRO="Mud" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_2" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="102.90" PETRO="Mud" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_3" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="103.00" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_3" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="103.25" INTV="1" INDEX_ZONE="-1" EGART="Lost_Data"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="103.69" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_3" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="104.00" PETRO="Mud" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_3" INTV="1"/>
</LAYERS>
```

and using following xslt code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exclude-result-prefixes=" xml xsl xs">
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:key name="adj" match="LAYER" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::LAYER[not(@STRAT = current()/@STRAT)][1])" />
    <xsl:template match="/*">

        <xsl:for-each select="LAYER[generate-id() = generate-id(key('adj', generate-id(preceding-sibling::LAYER[not(@STRAT = current()/@STRAT)][1]))[1])]">
            <xsl:variable name="INTVID" select="@INTV"/>
            <xsl:variable name="precedingZone" select="preceding-sibling::LAYER[@INTV = $INTVID][1]"/>
            <xsl:variable name="DEPTHFROM" select="$precedingZone/@DEPTHTO"/>
            
                <xsl:if test="@STRAT != ''">
                    <xsl:variable name="current-group" select="key('adj', generate-id(preceding-sibling::LAYER[not(@STRAT = current()/@STRAT)][1]))" />
                    <xsl:text>ZONE "</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@STRAT"/>
                    <xsl:text>" </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$current-group">
                        <xsl:sort select="$DEPTHFROM" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position() = 1 ">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$DEPTHFROM"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$current-group">
                        <xsl:sort select="@DEPTHTO" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position() = 1 ">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@DEPTHTO"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@INDEX_ZONE"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the result looks like that:

```
ZONE "geologiscal_formation_1"  94.00 
ZONE "geologiscal_formation_1" 94.20 95.00 
ZONE "geologiscal_formation_2" 95.00 101.80 
ZONE "geologiscal_formation_3" 101.80 103.00 
ZONE "geologiscal_formation_3" 103.25 104.00
```

But the desired output should look like that:

```
ZONE "geologiscal_formation_1" 0.00 95.00
ZONE "geologiscal_formation_2" 95.00 101.80 
ZONE "geologiscal_formation_3" 101.80 104.00
```

More background information:
Since the first line gives a DEPTHTO data only, i assume it starts at 0, as long not known.
The grouping does work partly only, because we got some layers with "lost_data", which brings all the idea to a bad result.

So i need some kind of condition, that ignores/skips data where "lost_data" is found. But since im using "for-each" i dont know how to accomplish that.
I heard of some "pipeline processing" but havent looked much into it, since im already overwhelmed with what i got.

Maybe someone knows better?

And ye, im stuck on xslt 1.0 :)

Thanks for any ideas or help.

Thanks to the answer and with some minor changes i was able to achive my goal:

the changes look like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exclude-result-prefixes=" xml xsl xs">
  <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="layer-by-strat" match="LAYER" use="@STRAT" />
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each select="LAYER[not(@EGART='Lost_Data')][count(. | key('layer-by-strat', @STRAT)[1]) = 1]">
      <xsl:variable name="INTVID" select="@INTV"/>
      <xsl:variable name="precedingZone" select="preceding-sibling::LAYER[@INTV = $INTVID][1]"/>
      <xsl:variable name="DEPTHFROM" select="$precedingZone/@DEPTHTO"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$precedingZone">
          <xsl:text>ZONE "</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="@STRAT" />
          <xsl:text>" </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="$DEPTHFROM"/>
          <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="key('layer-by-strat', @STRAT)[last()]/@DEPTHTO" />
          <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:text>ZONE "</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="@STRAT" />
          <xsl:text>" 0.00 </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="key('layer-by-strat', @STRAT)[last()]/@DEPTHTO" />
          <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't follow the logic you want to apply here. Isn't the desired result simply 0 to the last (or maximum) value of `DEPTHTO` (possibly grouped by `STRAT`)?

Comment: So you just need the min and max from `@DEPTHTO` where `@STRAT` has a value,  and min is always 0.0?

Comment: Hey you, total right, the example wasnt good. I edited it, and hope its more clear now what i mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you show can be produced quite easily using:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="layer-by-strat" match="LAYER" use="@STRAT" />

<xsl:template match="LAYERS" >
    <xsl:for-each select="LAYER[not(@EGART='Lost_Data')][count(. | key('layer-by-strat', @STRAT)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:text>ZONE "</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@STRAT" />
        <xsl:text>" 0.00 </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('layer-by-strat', @STRAT)[last()]/@DEPTHTO" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming the last `LAYER` in each group has the wanted maximum value - otherwise a minor adjustment will be required.

---

### Added:

I notice I have missed a part of the requirement where each layer begins at the maximal depth of the previous one. Here is the adjusted stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="layer-by-strat" match="LAYER" use="@STRAT" />

<xsl:template match="LAYERS" >
    <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
        <xsl:with-param name="layers" select="LAYER[not(@EGART='Lost_Data')][count(. | key('layer-by-strat', @STRAT)[1]) = 1]"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generate-rows">
    <xsl:param name="layers" select="/.."/>
    <xsl:param name="accumulated-depth" select="'0.00'"/>
    <xsl:if test="$layers">
        <xsl:variable name="strat" select="$layers[1]/@STRAT" />
        <xsl:variable name="max-depth" select="key('layer-by-strat', $strat)[last()]/@DEPTHTO" />
        <!-- output -->
        <xsl:text>ZONE "</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$strat" />
        <xsl:text>" </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$accumulated-depth" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$max-depth" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="layers" select="$layers[position() > 1]"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="accumulated-depth" select="$max-depth"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks,

with some minor changes i was able to achive the result :)

Comment: I have added an adjusted version which I believe handles the required changes.

Comment: Hey, it appears i forgot about the INTV attribute.
How can i generate te key using @STRAT only where INTV =1?

In my example all INTV =1 , but thats not the case in the data set :/

Comment: I suppose you want to add another predicate of `@INTV=1` to  the `$layers` param - and possibly also to the key definition (I am afraid I do not see the entire picture).

Comment: Since your answer did solve my question, ill make a new question with the new scenario :) its weird stuff i got here