# XSLT grouping siblings with conditions, part2?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

i got a similar question already, but that one is a little more complicated.

I am trying to get a text result of some geological layer data from an XML using xslt.

The XML sample i got may look like that:

```
<LAYERS> 
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="1.00" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_1" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="94.00" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_1" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="94.20" INTV="1" INDEX_ZONE="-1" EGART="Lost_Data"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="95.00" PETRO="Gravel" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_1" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="100.00" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_2" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="100.50" PETRO="Mud" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_2" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="101.50" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_2" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="101.80" PETRO="Mud" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_2" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="102.90" PETRO="Mud" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_3" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="103.00" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_3" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="103.25" INTV="1" INDEX_ZONE="-1" EGART="Lost_Data"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="103.69" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_3" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="104.00" PETRO="Mud" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_3" INTV="1"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="1.00" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_1" INTV="2"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="94.00" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_1" INTV="2"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="94.20" INTV="2" INDEX_ZONE="-1" EGART="Lost_Data"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="95.00" PETRO="Gravel" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_2" INTV="2"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="100.00" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_2" INTV="2"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="100.50" PETRO="Mud" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_4" INTV="2"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="101.50" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_4" INTV="2"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="101.80" PETRO="Mud" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_5" INTV="2"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="102.90" PETRO="Mud" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_3" INTV="2"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="103.00" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_3" INTV="2"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="103.25" INTV="2" INDEX_ZONE="-1" EGART="Lost_Data"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="103.69" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_2" INTV="2"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="104.00" PETRO="Mud" STRAT="geologiscal_formation_2" INTV="2"/>



</LAYERS>
```

its like 2 layer descriptions, which only differ in the INTV attribute value.

Im looking for a way to group by attribute STRAT of specific INTV and a result should look like that (lets say from INTV= 1 dataset):

```
ZONE "geologiscal_formation_1" 0.00 95.00
ZONE "geologiscal_formation_2" 95.00 101.80 
ZONE "geologiscal_formation_3" 101.80 104.00
```

The tricky part is to "ignore" the data with EGART="Lost_Data" in the grouping.

Since that question got partly answered here:
[XSLT grouping siblings with conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72126598/xslt-grouping-siblings-with-conditions)

but i made a mistake in my example, i did a new question for that new scanrio.

I hope my idea gets throu and ill keep searching.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: Is it possible to have a LAYER whose INTV is **not** 1 that has  a STRAT which no LAYER with INTV of 1 has?

Comment: Hey michael, thanks for the question. Yes, the scenario is possible. In STRAT can be basicly anything a human being comes up with :) ill edit the dataset a little for that regard :) thx again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the result you show, you could make a rather simple adjustment to the answer from your previous question:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="layer-by-strat" match="LAYER[@INTV=1]" use="@STRAT" />

<xsl:template match="LAYERS" >
    <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
        <xsl:with-param name="layers" select="LAYER[@INTV=1 and not(@EGART='Lost_Data')][count(. | key('layer-by-strat', @STRAT)[1]) = 1]"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generate-rows">
    <xsl:param name="layers" select="/.."/>
    <xsl:param name="accumulated-depth" select="'0.00'"/>
    <xsl:if test="$layers">
        <xsl:variable name="strat" select="$layers[1]/@STRAT" />
        <xsl:variable name="max-depth" select="key('layer-by-strat', $strat)[last()]/@DEPTHTO" />
        <!-- output -->
        <xsl:text>ZONE "</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$strat" />
        <xsl:text>" </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$accumulated-depth" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$max-depth" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="layers" select="$layers[position() > 1]"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="accumulated-depth" select="$max-depth"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that we are assuming here that a `LAYER` with `@EGART='Lost_Data'` does not have a `STRAT` attribute - so this condition can be skipped in the key definition.

--
P.S. It seems you would want to parametrize the choice of `INTV` - however, that's not possible (at least not if you want to use the Muenchian grouping method) because in XSLT 1.0 you are not allowed to use a variable in a match pattern .

Comment: Hey michael, it seems to work as intented :) Yes, the parametrizing of INTV is part of my idea, but i can live without it too :) I was surprised u spotted that :) Thanks a lot, ill try to implement + adjust the part into the whole stylesheet and wish for my best ;) You are a genius.

Comment: Which processor are you using?

Comment: msxml6, basicly what microsoft windows comes with :/

Comment: Im trying to implement your templates to my already existing ones, and it seems to have a conflict/just one template working. Do you know a way how to use multiple templates and give them some kind of order? i got all on match="/*".

Comment: I am afraid I couldn't possibly answer this in a comment. Perhaps this can help: https://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/.

Comment: hey, thanks :) i have a look into it. but those template-rules seem to be the reason for my problem. ill try to figure out.

Comment: Hey, i posted the question with some dataset in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72141180/xslt-multiple-templates-in-stylsheet-with-same-match
maybe my idea is better explained there?